# XAML & Windows Mobile (.Net Compact Framework)

Tags: .net, xaml, windows-mobile, compact-framework

Is there any support for XAML on the Windows Mobile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you could check out [this](http://mobileui.codeplex.com/) project over there at sourceforge. it provides some kind of basic xaml support to create windows mobile UI´s.

Answer (score 4):

Not from Microsoft, no.  [Windows CE R3 added a Silverlight](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/products/windowsce/silverlightforwe.mspx) (XAML) engine, but it's for native code only, and it's not yet propagated into any WinMo images.