# Silverlight XAML to Windows Mobile 6.1/6.5 forms?

Tags: c#, windows, silverlight, xaml, mobile

Is it possible or practical to have a system in a Windows Mobile 6.1/6.5 app which takes in a silverlight XAML file and creates a representation of said XAML file with form controls?

So I guess my questions are as follows:

1) Is it practical to do?

2) How can it be done (are there any good XML parses that could be used?)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's practical to implement the whole XAML engine, including resources, dependency properties etc. Google for Xamlon, looks like they tried and gave up. Even Mono and Moonlight haven't tried target Windows Mobile. **UPDATE**: Moonlight just [announced](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2011/Feb-16.html) new feature “Platform Abstraction Layer” giving the potential to port it to any platform.

If very basic subset of XAML is enough for you, check this post: [XAML & Windows Mobile (.Net Compact Framework)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650688/xaml-windows-mobile-net-compact-framework) The mentioned project has a basic XAML parser.